# Error 404 al retornar imagen desde api rest

Tags: laravel

Tengo un api en laravel en un servidor apache. El proyecto lo tengo en dos directorios, uno de nombre *api* ubicado en la raíz del directorio donde tenemos ubicado todos los archivos de la lógica del negocio y en la carpeta public_html hay un subdirectorio de nombre *data* con los archivos públicos tales como:

- *.htaccess*,
- *index.php*,
- *robots.txt* y
- *web.config*

Estoy cargando imágenes a través de la api y se guardan correctamente en `api/storage/app/public/user_avatar`, y al momento de retornarlas las retorno con una url generada de la forma: `https:\\www.dominio.co\data\storage\user-avatar\slsls.JPG`, pero esta URL me retorna error 404 al momento de abrila. Por lo que entiendo está buscando la imagen que está en la carpeta 'api' y no en la carpeta 'data' que es donde se aloja realmente.

¿Habría forma de que en el momento que se haga la petición, moverla? ¿O de qué forma se podría tener acceso a ese directorio y retornar la imagen a través del endpoint?

Comment: Puedes crear un link simbólico llamado `storage` en el mismo directorio donde tienes el `index.php` que apunte al directorio `tu-proyecto/storage/app/public/` donde están los archivos. Algo así  `ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink`

Comment: Disculpa esto lo haria en algun script .php independiente?

Comment: Es algo a nivel sistema operativo, un comando linux (no tiene que ver con php). Abre una terminal y corre el comando. No encuentro una respuesta en español, pero puedes guiarte por [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45825890/7498116). También en la [doc de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk) explican de qué va ese link simbólico, pero en tu caso tendrás que crearlo manualmente (y no con artisan) ya que la estructura de directorios no es la convencional